# Finding patterns from all files in directory generating individual outputs

Tags: while-loop, grep

I am trying to find the patterns from all *.txt files in a folder which are lists of numbers in lines. I want to find the lines that contain such numbers in a file that contains a mess of things in *.vcf format. The different lists must produce different output files that show that should be something like file.output.
I have tried this but does not work (sorry, Im quite newbie) Maybe I could use awk or other more fancy stuff?

```
    for file in ./*.txt
    do
    cat $file|while read LINE
    do
    grep "$LINE" ./AC-AN-table.v2.vcf > "$file.output"
    done
```

Comment: what do you want your output file to contain? samples from your input and hopeful output would be helpful.

Comment: If you were to provide sample input and expected output, It would be easier to provide an answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it this way :

```
ls *.txt | perl -nle 'system("grep -f $_ ./AC-AN-table.v2.vcf > $_.output");
```

*Explanations :* 
perl -nle is looping over the input, and executing the specified perl expression in each loop. More info at [perlrun](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html), but in short :

```
  -n : loop over input without autoprinting
  -l : modify line endings
  -e : expression to execute
```

The `-f` option to grep supplies a file with a list of patterns to search for. 1 pattern per line.